# Дискретная математика

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

По таблице истинности найти формулы, определяющие функции
f1(x1,x2,x3), f2(x1,x2,x3), и придать им более простой вид:[image: скриншот]

Comment: и в чем загвоздка? f1 то вообще из области очевидного

Comment: Строите [СКНФ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) или СДНФ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1 = не (x1 и x2 и x3)

f2 = не (x1 или x2)
f2 = (не (x1 или x2)) и (x3 или не x3)
```

последний пример если надо как-то все таки использовать x3 :)

Comment: второе не работает на последнем примере

Comment: @teran, да, переусердствовал, не смог вовремя остановиться :)

Comment: и аргументы нельзя наверное уж игнорировать )

Comment: надо там как нить тупо невелировать этот х3, типа Или х3 и не х3

Comment: @teran, кто сказал? если надо его все таки использовать, тогда можно `(не (x1 или x2)) и (x3 или не x3)` сделать :)

Comment: @teran, с чего? `(x3 или не x3)` - это строго 1 и когда я ее делаю and с любым результатом, то получаю конкретно тот результат